# Serving static content with reactor

Tags: java, netty, project-reactor

I want to make my reactor-service expose some static html with status information.
projectreactor.io uses reactor-netty for that and it works perfectly for serving single stand-alone files:

```
HttpServer http = HttpServer.create("0.0.0.0", 8100);
http.directory("/static", someLocalPath);
http.start().subscribe();
```

But as soon, as the html references another file, the request for the referenced file keeps pending in the browser and never finishes.
E.g. an index.html with the following content:

```
<html><body>
    <img src="http://localhost:8100/static/small.jpg" />
</body></html>
```

Here the browser shows status 200 for the index.html and status "pending" for small.jpg

Directly requesting only the small.jpg works without problems.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in 0.5.1.RELEASE of reactor-netty.
It's fixed in 0.5.2.RELEASE.

Thanks to Simon Baslé @ reactor